# memory leak in a 2D array with pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-leaks, 2d

I have a function using a 2D array and I want to copy data from one array to another and I used a tmp array, but valgrind kept on saying I have memory leak. I can't figure out why. The following is part of a function.

```
   // valgrind gave me error as operator new[] (unsigned long) for the following line
   T** temp_pointer = new T*[rows];
   for (int i=0; i < rows; i++) {
            temp_pointer[i] = new T[columns];
   }

   for (int i =0; i< rows; i++) {
      for (int j =0; j < (columns-3); j++) {
             temp_pointer[i][j] = Arry[i][j];
    }
      temp_pointer[i][columns -3 ] = myvalue1;
      temp_pointer[i][columns-2] = myvalue2;
      temp_pointer[i][columns-1] = myvalue3;
   }
   for ( int i =0; i< rows; i++)
         delete [] Arry[i];

    delete [] Arry;
    Arry= temp_pointer;
```

I also have a destructor which recursively delete the Arry pointers. Arry is private member of a template class.

I just could not figure out why it was a memory leak. Am I supposed to recursively delete temp_pointer ?? (I tried and it didn't work)
I just didn't know where did it leak?

Comment: Could you show us where you first define "Arry"?
And perhaps you should edit your formatting with your indentation - particularly with your for loops. (and your second inner for loop is missing a ")" . )

Comment: Arry is private of a class and is a pointer to T**. I indented more now and added the ")"

Comment: I updated the code and hopefully it is clearler. the memory leak was on the T** statement.

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear why valgrind claims that the memory is being leaked, but you clearly have an out of bound access in your loop.

```
temp_pointer[i][columns] = myvalue;
```

The index of the last element of an array is not its `size`, it is `(size-1)`. Writing into a location outside of the array's bound could clobber the memory allocator's housekeeping information and cause valgrind to complain.

Comment: I updated it, it was a typo on my part. I just can't figure out why valgrind shows that it is an error from a context. DrMemory shows that it is an error.

Comment: It is very difficult to judge abouth the error from such a small piece of code, but it appears that at the very last iteration, after you freed the `Arry`, you are assigning to `Arry` `temp_pointer`, which never gets deleted.

Comment: the above it part of a function and Arry is a private member of a class, do I need to delete temp_pointer? I thought it would be removed at the end of the function. But then I did try to do a delete temp_pointer, it gave me incorrect result and I am not sure why.